# Behavior of Select expressions containing select

Tags: select, sqlite

Consider the following setup:

```
CREATE TABLE NAMES(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Name text);

INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(1,'Tom');
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(2,'Lucy');
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(3,'Frank');

CREATE TABLE fields(fid integer, fname text);
INSERT into fields values(1, "Id");
insert into fields values(2, "Name");

SELECT name, (SELECT "Name") FROM NAMES;
```

The last statement will output

```
Tom|Tom
Lucy|Lucy
Frank|Frank
```

However, although `select fname from fields where fid=2` yields `("Name")` (as a single-cell table), replacing the last statement in the above query by

```
SELECT name, (select fname from fields where fid=2) FROM NAMES;
```

gives

```
Tom|Name
Lucy|Name
Frank|Name
```

Why? Is this intended?

Note: This has been tested using SQLite v3.20

Comment: yes, this works as intended. If you want to use a value (`"Name"`) as a column, you need dynamic SQL.

Comment: @yper-trollᵀᴹ and why does the former expression yield its output, despite it contains a `select` to obtain the field name? Is it because the result of the `select`ion is independent of the database contents?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. `SELECT name, (SELECT "Name") FROM NAMES;` is equivalent to `SELECT name, "Name" FROM NAMES;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL, `'single quotes'` are used for string values, while `"double quotes"` are used for table/column names.

SQLite [allows all types of quotes](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) for compatibility with other databases, but it uses the correct interpretation first, if possible.

So in the subquery `(SELECT "Name")`, it will try to use a column named `Name`, and there is one. In other words, the first query is interpreted as:

```
SELECT NAMES.Name, (SELECT NAMES.Name) FROM NAMES;
```

(The subquery just refers to the value in the current row of the outer query; this is a rather pointless instance of a [correlated subquery](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#cosub).)

---

SQLite is designed as an embedded database that is accessed from a 'real'
 programming language, so it has no built-in mechanism for dynamic SQL. You have to do the column name lookup separately:

```py
cursor = db.execute("select fname from fields where fid = ?", [2])
fname = cursor.fetchone()[0]
cursor = db.execute("SELECT name, {} FROM NAMES".format(fname))
for name, othercolumn in cursor:
    ...
```

Comment: I do not remember having read this double- vs. single quotes issue. Thank you for pointing me to that; with single quotes, the behaviour indeed is different.